# How to open a web page on my Linux desktop from PuTTY?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, putty

I would like to be able to open a web page on the desktop of my Linux (Ubuntu) from PuTTY. It is not a question there I think of X11, perhaps of display I do not know but my objective is really to know how to enter a command on PuTTY, which could allow me to launch an Internet page on the desktop of my Ubuntu machine, so that when I connect to it by RDP the page in question is really opened, exactly as if I opened the terminal Ubuntu and wrote:

```
 firefox https://xxxxxx/xxxxxxx
```

I do not want to visualize in any way any page on PuTTY, it is really just:

> “PuTTY opens on the desktop of the machine you are connected to, an internet page and go to such and such a site.”

If ever PuTTY is not able to do it but such and such other application allows it, obviously it would be with pleasure that I would take note of this one, or even if the thing to do is rather to try to control by PuTTY the internal terminal of my Ubuntu, don't bother to explain me how, because it would solve my problem.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. If your RDP into an Ubuntu machine, you can run `firefox https://xxxxxx/xxxxxxx` and then the page will open up in Firefox on Ubuntu. But if you remote in via PuTTY (SSH I assume) and run the command, the results are the same. So unclear what the issue is here.

Comment: so my problem is indeed a display issue, because when I write on putty(ssh) terminal this command, here is what I get "Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified"

Comment: If you SSH into a machine, your whole “display” is the SSH connection.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh#_=_